# ScrollView is not working in react-native

Tags: react-native

scrollView doesn't work in react-native. It started working one time automatically but before I was facing same issue and then it stopped working again after some changes in content while it was `vertical`. but when I set `Horozontal={true}`  it didn't worked once.It works if there's only `text` in `scrollView` but if i add `view` it stops working. Is there any permanent solution or alternative for this?

```
     <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.ScrollView}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
         <Text>asdas asdhs</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>asdas asdhs</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>asdas asdhs</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>asdas asdhs</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      {/* </View> */}
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    // flex: 1,
    width: 150,
    height: 200,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    marginVertical: '10%',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    borderRadius: 25,
    opacity: 0.9,
    top: -15,
  },
  ScrollView: {
    // justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView is a component which doesn't inherit the use of flex.
Remove flex: 1 from ScrollView style and it will work.